# How do I enable Hikari CP instead of default Hibernate connection pool?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, hikaricp

I got the following hibernate error on my server.

```
The internal connection pool has reached its maximum size and no connection is currently available!
```

It turns out that the application is using the default hibernate Connection Pool and warns that it is not meant for production. I did some reading and want to change it to HikariCP but I am not able to do so. I have tried the following.

1. `spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource` It just ignores this, has no effect
2. `change spring.datasource.url to spring.datasource.hikari.jdbc-url` This cause it to crash because it is expecting the first one.

---

I am confused because some docs suggest that Hikari is the default CP for Spring boot and I don't need to do anything else to use it. What exactly do I need to change to use HikariCP instead of Hibernate default CP. I have gone through some tutorials and similar questions but nothing seems to work.

---

**Note:**
I just noticed that inside my Hibernate config class, I have a datasource bean which is returning a [PGSimpleDataSource](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/ds/PGSimpleDataSource.html) which says that it does not perform pooling. I don't know how this affects me. What all do I need to change in order to prevent my original error and use HikariCP ?

Comment: Ditch your `DataSource` bean and configure the appropriate `spring.datasource` properties in your `application.properties`, that should be all you need (unless you are doing more manual configuration which you didn't explain). Looks like you are working around some of the Spring Boot features instead of using/embracing them.